# Historical Data on Air Transport Passenger-km/Country

Tags: transportation, climate, aviation

I am looking for historical data on air transport passenger-km by country (or geographic region). 
So far, I was able to find:

| source | years | coverage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [World Bank (ICAO Data)](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IS.AIR.PSGR) | 1970-now | country-level |
| [ICAO Annual Reports](https://www.icao.int/about-icao/Pages/annual-reports.aspx) | 2007-now | geographic region |
| [OECD Data Explorer](https://data-explorer.oecd.org/vis?tm=transport&pg=0&snb=89&vw=tl&df%5Bds%5D=dsDisseminateFinalDMZ&df%5Bid%5D=DSD_AIR_TRANSPORT%2540DF_AIR_TRANSPORT&df%5Bag%5D=OECD.SDD.NAD.SEEA&df%5Bvs%5D=1.0&pd=%25%2C2%2CC&dq=.A.......&to%5BTIME_PERIOD%5D=false) | 2013-now | OECD countries |
| [Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Passenger_transport_statistics&oldid=8625) | ????-now | EU countries |

What sources could I use to back to the 1950s with my data coverage? 
Alternatively, I would appreciate data on aviation fuel use by country per year. Perhaps this has better coverage.